# what server is sccm patching now

Tags: windows, automation, patch, dashboard, sccm

im currently patching my servers through SCCM using a ADR rule. and i have noticed that theres no order in installing updates to servers. random servers get patched during the maintenance window.

i want to know a way to get which server is getting patched now so that i can read the information and put it into a dashboard. then the onduty person can know exactly whats going on. SCCM has controlled access so i need to find a automated way to show the info.

I have two questions

1. is there a log i can read to get the info i need.I need

   ***server name,
    patch started time,
    patch end time, reboot info (if possible)***
2. A hassle free way for me to read the info and display it on our monitor?

hope someone would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you could get the patch started time, patch end time,  from the Windowsupdate.log. [How to read the Windowsupdate.log file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093)

Meanwhile, using the query below to get the consolidated Report for all your deployments

```
Select Deploymentname, Available, Deadline, 

cast(cast(((cast([Compliant] as float) / (ISNULL([Compliant], 0) + ISNULL([Enforcement state unknown], 0) + ISNULL([Successfully installed update(s)], 0) + ISNULL([Failed to install update(s)], 0) + ISNULL([Installing update(s)], 0) + ISNULL([Waiting for another installation to complete], 0) + ISNULL([Pending system restart], 0) + ISNULL([Downloading update(s)], 0)))*100) as Numeric(10,2)) as varchar(256)) + '%' AS '%Compliant', 

  [Compliant], 

  [Enforcement state unknown], 

  [Successfully installed update(s)], 

  [Failed to install update(s)], 

  [Installing update(s)], 

  [Waiting for another installation to complete], 

  [Pending system restart], 

  [Downloading update(s)] 

From 

(select 

a.AssignmentName as DeploymentName, 

a.StartTime as Available, 

a.EnforcementDeadline as Deadline, 

sn.StateName as LastEnforcementState, 

count(*) as NumberOfComputers 

from v_CIAssignment a 

join v_AssignmentState_Combined assc 

on a.AssignmentID=assc.AssignmentID 

join v_StateNames sn 

on assc.StateType = sn.TopicType and sn.StateID=isnull(assc.StateID,0) 

group by a.AssignmentName, a.StartTime, a.EnforcementDeadline, 

      sn.StateName) as PivotData 

PIVOT 

( 

SUM (NumberOfComputers) 

FOR LastEnforcementState IN 

( [Compliant], 

  [Enforcement state unknown], 

  [Successfully installed update(s)], 

  [Failed to install update(s)], 

  [Installing update(s)], 

  [Waiting for another installation to complete], 

  [Pending system restart], 

  [Downloading update(s)]) 

) AS pvt
```

[Software Updates Views in Configuration Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn581945.aspx)

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: im really sorry for taking this much time to answer. but i ran into a problem. how can i modify this to show failed/installed/available updates by server wise?
basically the same attributes per server. this is per deployement

thanks alot for the help :)